# MVVM Webservice not holding data returned

Tags: vb.net, wcf, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I would like to create an application that is gong to connect to a web service and return some data. I have been following a few tutorials and have the following code:

```
Public Class ItemViewModel
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
Private _Name As String

Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If Not value.Equals(_Name) Then
            _Name = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name")
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

..... along with other properties resembling the table from my database.

I then have a MainViewModel

```
Private _Customer As New CustomerService.Customer   

Public Sub LoadData()
    Dim myService As New CustomerService.CustomerClient

    myService.GetCustomerByNameAsync("Andy")
    AddHandler myService.GetCustomerByNameCompleted, AddressOf CustomerByName

    Items.Add(NewItemViewModel With {.Name = _Customer.Name})

 End Sub

Private Sub CustomerByName(sender As Object, e As CustomerService.GetCustomerByNameCompletedEventArgs)
    _Customer = e.Result
End Sub
```

The problem i have is the service returns data when i check with WCF test tool but on this occasion when running the app i keep getting an empty object for _Customer. I have tried making it into a shared variable but nothing seems to hold the data i get from the service.

How i could hold the data in my MainViewModel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that GetCustomerByNameAsync execute asynchronously so `Items.Add(NewItemViewModel With {.Name = _Customer.Name})` execute before the service respon and the code inside `CustomerByName` execute. If you move the Add code inside the event handler (CustomerByName) it should work like you want.